# Eclipse CDT: How to clear Problems window without invoking Clean Project or Build Project?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, manual

Is there a way to clear the Problems window (and any related source code error/warning annotations) without invoking "Build All/Project/..." or "Clean project" (or deleting the project and then re-creating/re-importing it)?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, in the problems view:

1. Right Click > Select All  (or
   ctrl-A)
2. Right Click > Delete

All the markers are then deleted.

Comment: This is not a solution for me, as I got over 3k error, and the window only show 100 at a time.
Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and Delete is not available when I select all problems.

Comment: Try to build your project and if its succsess and still IDE shows Errors in problem section then this works because these are not real errors anymore

Answer (score 3):

It is also not best solution, but when you configure Problems view (using menus under arrow icon) you can turn limit off and then select and deleta all errors.

Comment: This is it. Best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can set `limit visible items` through the down arrow in the top right side of problems views then click `preferences`, type your limit, for example (1000):

[image]

after that by :

> right click in the problems view -> select all,
>   right click again -> delete.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If Using Checkstyle, then go to the `Project-> Right Click -> Checkstyle -> Clear Violations.`

This will clear the Problems Window of all the Errors, Warnings reported via Checkstyle